# The Major differences between HTML and XAML?

Tags: html, xaml

I searched Google for the differences between `HTML` and `XAML`, but did not get relevant results.

So I want to know why we are using `XAML(WPF)` instead of `HTM`L and it's differences.

Comment: They have nothing at all in common except visual similarity.

Comment: The reason why you're not getting any results is because it doesn't make sense to compare them in the first place.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943579/how-unique-is-xaml

Answer (score 0):

XAML is the language behind the visual presentation of an application that you develop in Microsoft Expression Blend, just as HTML is the language behind the visual presentation of a Web page.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this](http://www.freewebs.com/mono4mano/apps/blog/show/1194442-difference-between-xml-and-xaml).You can know the differences.

Comment: While the prospect is faulty from the start, this article doesn't even mention HTML - how do you expect it to help someone who thinks XAML and HTML are comparable?